# Custom sorting a 2-D array of large integers

Tags: java

I have a 2-d array of integers which I want to sort by their second index. I am using the following custom comparator :

```
Comparator<int[]> cmp = (a,b) ->  {
            if (a[1] == b[1])
                return a[0] - b[0];
            return a[1] - b[1];
        };
Arrays.sort(points, cmp);
```

However, for large integer values it gives wrong answer due to overflow. Example :

```
int[][] points = {{-2147483646,-2147483645},{2147483646,2147483647}};
```

Is there a way to handle this efficiently without explicitly handling these overflow cases? For example :

```
Comparator<int[]> cmp = (a,b) ->  {
            if (a[1] < 0 && b[1] > 0)
                return -1;
            if (a[1] > 0 && b[1] < 0)
                return 1;
            if (a[1] == b[1])
                return a[0] - b[0];
            return a[1] - b[1];
        };
```

Comment: If you're worried about integer overflow, couldn't you just use `long` type instead of `int`?

Comment: Or even `BigInteger`? Also, why do you need your own Comparator or use subtraction vs using `Integer.compare`?

Comment: Yes. ```Integer.compare``` works. Thank you.